# xampp не видит php?

Tags: xampp

Пытаюсь развернуть проект на symfony 3 на windows.

1) Установил xampp

2) Установил composer для windows

2) закинул проект в папку htdocs в xampp

3) дальше пытаюсь установить composer в проекте через терминал командой composer install, но получаю ошибку (php не видит)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В переменные среды в path указал путь до php и composer

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Добрый вечер. Если Вы глобально установили composer, то зачем ставить его ещё и в проекте?

Comment: @slo_nik Я скачал exe файл установки composer для windows после установки появилась папка c:\composer в которой 3 файла, а в проекте у меня есть composer.lock в котором куча зависимостей которые нужны для проекта, я просто не работал до этого на windows поэтому возникли проблемы